# meaning of the phrase "on the minute"?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> Squats use 2 reps, usually for 10 sets, while bench presses and presses typically use sets of 3, again for 10 sets; both are done with a one-minute rest between sets.Deadlifts work well with 15 singles on a 30-second clock. Weighted chin-ups have even been done this way. It works best to take each set out of the rack **on the minute**, re-rack it quickly after the set, and focus on the next set during the rest.

Comment: I've recalled the phrase [on the hour](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-hour), not sure if it fits though.

Answer (score 3):

*On the minute* means the moment when the minutes change, i.e., when the seconds are 0. It will help to have a clock that shows the seconds. If you have a digital clock that does not show seconds, you can watch for the moment when the minutes value changes.

It is a fairly unusual phrase, but it is based on the more common *on the hour*, meaning when the hour changes.

Comment: Right, just like on the hour.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it means "in a minute". I hear this phrase in workout contexts, like:

> “Every Minute **on the Minute**,” are a fun and creative way to
>   manipulate your work-rest ratio during workouts. A predetermined
>   number of reps are assigned for each set, and they must be completed
>   in a minute. If completed faster, a longer rest break may be taken. If
>   the exerciser moves slowly, however, he or she will have a limited
>   rest break before the next set. [(source)](https://www.acefitness.org/education-and-resources/lifestyle/blog/6535/emom-workout)

So in your sentence it means do each sets with a minute break, just like what the preceding part says.